# Lab: I am running 15.1 on a catalyst and need to disable redundant supervisormp

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, redundancy, cisco-6500, lab

I am trying to find a way to disable the redundant supervisor mode in my switch, as it is disabling another line card, so it can have enough power to spare for a redundant slot I wont use.

I have tried searching around and haven't found a way to do so.

Sup720 1x 6509 chassis, no redundant is installed, but the IOS keeps holding power for a slot I won't be using.

```
after doing show power 
Slot Card-Type          Watts   A @42V Watts   A @42V State State
---- ------------------ ------- ------ ------- ------ ----- -----
3    WS-X6148-45AF       107.94  2.57   107.94  2.57  on    on
5    WS-SUP720-3B        282.24  6.72   282.24  6.72  on    on
6    (Redundant Sup)       -     -      282.24  6.72  -     -
8    WS-X6148-GE-TX      103.74  2.47   103.74  2.47  on    on
9    WS-X6748-GE-TX      407.40  9.70     -     -     on    off (FRU-power denied)
system power total =     1153.32 Watts (27.46 Amps @ 42V)
system power used =       832.86 Watts (19.83 Amps @ 42V)
system power available =  320.46 Watts ( 7.63 Amps @ 42V)
```

Update:

The simple solution was since the x6748 can go in any slot I put it in the slot6 so that it could use the already reserved power as part of its own.

```
Slot Card-Type          Watts   A @42V Watts   A @42V State State
---- ------------------ ------- ------ ------- ------ ----- -----
3    WS-X6148-45AF       107.94  2.57   107.94  2.57  on    on
5    WS-SUP720-3B        282.24  6.72   282.24  6.72  on    on
6    WS-X6748-GE-TX      407.40  9.70   407.40  9.70  on    on
8    WS-X6148-GE-TX      103.74  2.47   103.74  2.47  on    on
```

Comment: What switch model, and why can't you remove the redundant supervisor card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the power for any 6509 slot with the `no power enable module <slot number>` command.

Commands such as these are very easy to find on Cisco's web site. Cisco maintains extensive documentation on its products. A simple search turned up [*Power Management for Catalyst 6000 Series Switches*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/22389-142.html).

---

**Edit:**

Based on your edit of the `show power` command, your redundant supervisor slot is not actually using any power. Your switch simply doesn't have enough power to power the chassis and all the line cards you want to power. The 6748 line card uses a lot of power (a significant chunk of the power supply output). Not all the power of the power supply is available to the slots; much of it is used to power the chassis itself.

You could get a bigger power supply (the one you have is pretty small for a 6509; more appropriate in a 6506 or 6503), or you could add a second power supply.

Depending on your power supply, you may be able to use 220V to increase the available power.

Comment: The other solution is to stick my power supply in a 220v.  I will have to find a power conditioner for 220v before i could use that solution. looks like it is a quark of cisco's expectations of every one getting a backup sup for large chassis.